# Including .h and .c files to project on the IAR

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I am programming stm8s and sht20 from sensirion company with I2C on the IAR. I'm using sht20 sample code: [this link](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Sample_Codes_Software/Humidity_and_Temperature_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_and_Temperature_Sensors_SHT21_Sample_Code_V1.2.pdf)
I edited this sample code to my mcu. Then, for example I included i2c_hal.h to my main.c, but functions not working in my main.c file and IAR error is

```
ERROR LI005 no defition for I2c_Init()
Linking error
```

For example:

**main.c**

```
#include "stm8s.h"
#include "i2c_hal.h"

I2c_Init();
```

**i2c_hal.h**

```
#ifndef I2C_HAL_H
#define I2C_HAL_H

void I2c_Init ();
#endif
```

**i2c_hal.c**

```
#include "I2C_HAL.h"

void I2c_Init ()
{
 SDA=LOW;
 SCL=LOW; 
 SDA_CONF=LOW;
 SCL_CONF=LOW;
 SDA=HIGH;
 SCL=HIGH;
}
```

I copied sht20 files to my project directory. What should I do for this error?

Comment: You forgot an`#endif`

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: I added #endif to i2c_hal.h but i forgot add to my post sorry. I compiled this project, but i can't use functions in main.c file.

Comment: Everything looks ok. Are you sure that the `i2c_hal.c` file is taken into account during the build process ?

Comment: I am not sure but i know to should be include this my project.

Comment: @Kotshi asked you how are you compiling this. This is important, as external C files (libraries) need to be included to the linking process after beeing compiled.

Comment: You should avoid referring to the header file as both "I2C_HAL.h" and "i2c_hal.h", even if you are using Windows.  Some file-systems are case sensitive, and even if they are not some tools such as version control systems are; mixing case makes your code unnecessarily non-portable to other build or file repository environments.  Use the case as it appears in filesystem, or rename it to match whatever you choose to use.  I strongly suggest using lower-case exclusively.

Comment: I included codes of all header files to main.h and included main.h to my main.c, no linking error now.

Answer (score 3):

The header file is read by the preprocessor not the linker; if you get as far as linking, it is not a header file issue.  The three basic build steps for C code are:

- preprocess
- compile
- link

Your build is failing at the link state.  The linker requires *all* compiled object files and any necessary libraries that constitute your application as input.  In your case the most likely issue is that you have not compiled and linked i2c_hal.c (or strictly compiled i2c_hal.c and linked i2c_hal.obj).  In the IAR IDE you simply explicitly add i2c_hal.c to your project along with main.c, and all should be good (all other dependencies being satisfied).

I suspect that i2c_hal.c will infact fail compilation since it is missing any declaration of SDA, SCL etc. - you probably need to include stm8s.h there also.

In general the process looks like this (this diagram actually omits pre-processing - i.e. expansion of headers, macros and conditional compilation etc. - but it was the otherwise clearest example I found; the [original page](https://deficienzartificiale.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/compiler-linker-assembler-and-loader-an-overview/) does however mention the pre-processor stage, and the preprocessor is normally run automatically when you invoke the compiler in any case):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same issue with the spi. I got hal_spi_init() linking problem. To resolve the issue you need to enable the I2C in your stm32 hal drivers. In stm32xx_hal_conf.h file we have different #define modules. There you can enable the I2C module or just include the defined symbol in your IAR tool. Then Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the C source files to the project. Header files shall not have any code or data, only the declarations of types , extern variables, macros, static inline functions and function prototypes.